# Lodash mapping of nested collections

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have following collection:

```
var realty = {
  name: 'Realty A',
  entrances: [
    {
      name: 'Entrance A',
      units: [
        {name: 'unitA', contracts: [{contractNo: 'no.963'}, {contractNo: 'no.741'}]},
        {name: 'unitB', contracts: [{contractNo: 'no.789'}, {contractNo: 'no.564'}]}
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Entrance B',
      units: [
        {name: 'unitC', contracts: [{contractNo: 'no.419'}, {contractNo: 'no.748'}]},
        {name: 'unitD', contracts: [{contractNo: 'no.951'}, {contractNo: 'no.357'}]}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I am trying to extract collection of contracts.
I tried using lodash 'map' function as follows:
`_.map(realty, 'entrances.units.contracts')` but 'property' iterate does not work on arrays.

Any idea how can I extract collection of all contracts? Perhaps lodash chain could help but I am not sure how to use it :/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick

```
_(realty.entrances).flatMap('units').flatMap('contracts').value()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all contracts, using lodash:

```
_.map(realty.entrances, e => e.units.map(u => u.contracts));
```

Answer (score 0):

One posibility without lodash

```
var contractsArray = []

realty.entrances.forEach( e => {
 let units = e.units;
 units.forEach( u => contractsArray.push(u.contracts));
});
```